# Right design approach: Parsing xml

Tags: c#, xml

I get back a consolidated product xml that I receive by making a call to another .net application.
Xml contains data for various sub-products like P1,P2,P3,etc. I need to write a C# program to parse the xml and then break it into three separate xmls..i.e.one for each sub-product P1,P2,P3....etc. The business rule(or criteria)for parsing the xml for each of the sub-products is different.

In the future,the input xml may also contain information for new additional sub-products P4,P5 etc.
So I'll need to break this xml into those new sub-products as well.

From the module design perspective, the sub-product types and their parsing criterion should be extensible and configurable.This is so that when a new sub-product needs to be processed, just a config change is required and no code change is required.

So I was thinking of the following approach.Does it sound good enough?

1.Add a new look up table called T in the database.

2.Add 3 columns: Id(int), Sub-ProductName(varchar), Criteria(varchar)

3.To configure a Sub-Product say P1 in the database, the row could look like as follows:

```
1--P1--ProductType='XYZ'|ProductCategory='ABC'|
2--P2--....
3--P3--...
```

Here, ProductType and ProductCategory are valid element names in the input xml.

4.Then in the C# program, process the Criterion column value using reflection and apply the rules on the input xml to get the xml for the corresponding sub-product name i.e P1..

Thanks.

Comment: I like to start a project by designing the database architecture.  Having a good database always make the rest of the coding easier.I also like to use a datatable in c# as the primary interface between the database and the rest of the c# code.From a datatable you can display results easily to the DGV.Also read/write data to a xml file using the datatable Read/WriteXml() methods.I would also change the structure of the current xml files to match if WriteXml datatable method if not currently the same.Can't tell from your description if your approach is the same, but I think it's close to mine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to invoke an XSLT stylesheet (XSLT 2.0 or higher, so use Saxon or XmlPrime).

If the criteria were fixed then the stylesheet could do something like

```
<xsl:transform....>

<xsl:template match="P1">
   <xsl:result-document href="subproduct1.xml">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="P2">
   <xsl:result-document href="subproduct2.xml">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

...
</xsl:transform>
```

If changing this stylesheet when the product definitions change feels too much like "code change", then you could generate this stylesheet from some higher-level definition of the product structure. One of the benefits of XSLT is that, being XML, you can write an XSLT stylesheet (called a meta-stylesheet) to generate XSLT stylesheets. This isn't as exotic as it sounds; it's a fairly common practice.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your inputs. If the input is a serializable object, then would the approach that I mentioned suffice?Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what approach you have in mind or where being serializable comes into it; I'm just telling you how I would do it. (Design questions on StackOverflow are often rejected as being "opinion-based", and there's justification for that: you haven't stated any criteria that would allow one design to be judged objectively better than another.)